# How can I open a temporary "full-size" window inside another window in a tab to execute `:term`?

Tags: neovim

In order to execute `:term` in `nvim` without causing the current window in a **tab** to close on exit, I execute the following command:

`:vnew +term`

This splits the current window into two, one of which executes `:term`.

However, I really don't want to split the window, I just want to open a temporary window, inside the original window in a **tab**, to execute `:term`, so that when `:term` exits, I return to the original window.

Is that possible?

Comment: have you tried `:sh` then?

Comment: by the way what vim do you use? looks like neovim as vim auto split on `:term`

Comment: @MaximKim - it says "not an editor command" for `:sh`.

Comment: @MaximKim - I tagged the question `nvim`.

Comment: ah, missed it. `:sh` wasn't ported to nvim

Comment: but anyway, when you `:term` on neovim and then `exit` it -- it should go back to prev buffer

Comment: @MaximKim - also, if I execute `:term` in a tab?

Comment: Could `:tabnew +term` do the trick? When you `exit` the terminal, it'll close your tab, as with any buffer (just tested, just in case).

Answer (score 2):

In general that is how tab pages work in vim/neovim:

Excerpt from neovim help (`:h :tabc` and then one pageup):

```
CLOSING A TAB PAGE:

Closing the last window of a tab page closes the tab page too, unless there is
only one tab page.
```

When you have term as the only window in a tab page and "exit" it you close the last window.

I don't know your use case, but maybe [floaterm](https://github.com/voldikss/vim-floaterm) might be useful? If not as a plugin to use right away then maybe as inspiration to use rather big floating window with terminal inside?